# Error on Stateful Widget when import Modal class

Tags: flutter, dart

The code work fine when I am not importing the modal file.

[image]

When I import a modal dart file, the Stateful widget become warning line that make me cant build project.

[image: After import modal class]

Below is my modal.dart

```
class Merchant {


int id;
  String type;
  String name;
  String image;
  String address1;
  String address2;
  String address3;
  String city;
  String stateCode;
  String postcode;
  String countryCode;
  int priority;
  String createdAt;
  String updatedAt;
  String deletedAt;
  String email;
  String contact;
  String slug;
  String emailFinance;
  int isEmailFinance;
  String legalName;
  String legalRegistrationNumber;
  String bankSwiftCode;
  String bankAccountNumber;
  String imageUrl;
  String address;
  String merchantType;
  List<Currencies> currencies;
  State state;
  Country country;

  Merchant(
      {this.id,
        this.type,
        this.name,
        this.image,
        this.address1,
        this.address2,
        this.address3,
        this.city,
        this.stateCode,
        this.postcode,
        this.countryCode,
        this.priority,
        this.createdAt,
        this.updatedAt,
        this.deletedAt,
        this.email,
        this.contact,
        this.slug,
        this.emailFinance,
        this.isEmailFinance,
        this.legalName,
        this.legalRegistrationNumber,
        this.bankSwiftCode,
        this.bankAccountNumber,
        this.imageUrl,
        this.address,
        this.merchantType,
        this.currencies,
        this.state,
        this.country});

  Merchant.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    type = json['type'];
    name = json['name'];
    image = json['image'];
    address1 = json['address1'];
    address2 = json['address2'];
    address3 = json['address3'];
    city = json['city'];
    stateCode = json['state_code'];
    postcode = json['postcode'];
    countryCode = json['country_code'];
    priority = json['priority'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
    deletedAt = json['deleted_at'];
    email = json['email'];
    contact = json['contact'];
    slug = json['slug'];
    emailFinance = json['email_finance'];
    isEmailFinance = json['is_email_finance'];
    legalName = json['legal_name'];
    legalRegistrationNumber = json['legal_registration_number'];
    bankSwiftCode = json['bank_swift_code'];
    bankAccountNumber = json['bank_account_number'];
    imageUrl = json['image_url'];
    address = json['address'];
    merchantType = json['merchant_type'];
    if (json['currencies'] != null) {
      currencies = new List<Currencies>();
      json['currencies'].forEach((v) {
        currencies.add(new Currencies.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    state = json['state'] != null ? new State.fromJson(json['state']) : null;
    country =
    json['country'] != null ? new Country.fromJson(json['country']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['type'] = this.type;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['image'] = this.image;
    data['address1'] = this.address1;
    data['address2'] = this.address2;
    data['address3'] = this.address3;
    data['city'] = this.city;
    data['state_code'] = this.stateCode;
    data['postcode'] = this.postcode;
    data['country_code'] = this.countryCode;
    data['priority'] = this.priority;
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
    data['deleted_at'] = this.deletedAt;
    data['email'] = this.email;
    data['contact'] = this.contact;
    data['slug'] = this.slug;
    data['email_finance'] = this.emailFinance;
    data['is_email_finance'] = this.isEmailFinance;
    data['legal_name'] = this.legalName;
    data['legal_registration_number'] = this.legalRegistrationNumber;
    data['bank_swift_code'] = this.bankSwiftCode;
    data['bank_account_number'] = this.bankAccountNumber;
    data['image_url'] = this.imageUrl;
    data['address'] = this.address;
    data['merchant_type'] = this.merchantType;
    if (this.currencies != null) {
      data['currencies'] = this.currencies.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.state != null) {
      data['state'] = this.state.toJson();
    }
    if (this.country != null) {
      data['country'] = this.country.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Currencies {
  int id;
  int merchantId;
  String code;
  String name;
  String createdAt;
  String updatedAt;
  Null deletedAt;
  String balanceCacheType;

  Currencies(
      {this.id,
        this.merchantId,
        this.code,
        this.name,
        this.createdAt,
        this.updatedAt,
        this.deletedAt,
        this.balanceCacheType});

  Currencies.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    merchantId = json['merchant_id'];
    code = json['code'];
    name = json['name'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
    deletedAt = json['deleted_at'];
    balanceCacheType = json['balance_cache_type'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['merchant_id'] = this.merchantId;
    data['code'] = this.code;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
    data['deleted_at'] = this.deletedAt;
    data['balance_cache_type'] = this.balanceCacheType;
    return data;
  }
}

class State {
  int id;
  String iso;
  String iso3;
  String name;
  String nameAlternate;
  String type;
  String code;

  State(
      {this.id,
        this.iso,
        this.iso3,
        this.name,
        this.nameAlternate,
        this.type,
        this.code});

  State.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    iso = json['iso'];
    iso3 = json['iso3'];
    name = json['name'];
    nameAlternate = json['name_alternate'];
    type = json['type'];
    code = json['code'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['iso'] = this.iso;
    data['iso3'] = this.iso3;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['name_alternate'] = this.nameAlternate;
    data['type'] = this.type;
    data['code'] = this.code;
    return data;
  }
}

class Country {
  int id;
  String iso;
  String name;
  String iso3;
  int numcode;
  int phonecode;

  Country(
      {this.id, this.iso, this.name, this.iso3, this.numcode, this.phonecode});

  Country.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    iso = json['iso'];
    name = json['name'];
    iso3 = json['iso3'];
    numcode = json['numcode'];
    phonecode = json['phonecode'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['iso'] = this.iso;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['iso3'] = this.iso3;
    data['numcode'] = this.numcode;
    data['phonecode'] = this.phonecode;
    return data;
  }
}
```

I have few modal class. But only this one will gain error when I import it other dart file. I have try to find out the error but couldn't figure it out. Can someone help me to solve this problem? Thank you so much.

Comment: What is the error? you need to give a stack trace or at least the error string

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to separate you class in different file. Put Merchant in a dart file,
Currencies in another dart file and so one.